# Backing up my schema and database objects using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, schema, backup

I have a database that has a schema named lamb that has a number of database objects. I want to back up only the objects and data that are associated with the lamb schema and not the rest.

Is this possible ??? If so how ???

Answer (score 1):

It's Impossible unless you change their filegroup and create a filegroup for them, read this [Backup Overview (SQL Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477.aspx) for more details.